# Data Factory Create Nested Arrays from Flat File

Tags: azure-data-factory

```
Does any one know how to create an array within an array in Data Factory. I need to make something like this. One Employee has multiple Customers, each Customer buys multiple products.  Its coming from a flat file where Employee repeats multiple times once for each Customer then Customer repeats multiple times per Product. 
{
  "employeeNumber": "00001",
  "employeeName": "John Doe",
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": "99999",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "XYZ",
          "price": 2.00
        },
        {
          "name": "ABC",
          "price": 3.00
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1111",
      "name": "John Smith",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "RVS",
          "price": 2.00
        },
        {
          "name": "GHI",
          "price": 3.00
        },
        {
          "name": "QRS",
          "price": 4.00
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to create a double nested Array -- Array within and Array from Flat Data in a Data Factory Dataflow.  So much on how to "flatten" JSON to columns.. nothing on how to aggregate flat to "Nested" JSON in nested Arrays.

I was able to get a Struct in a Derived Column to create an Array but I am struggling with how to create another array under the first Array.

Answer (score 0):

To create arrays, use an Aggregate transformation and the "collect()" function. https://youtu.be/zneE18EHJSE

Answer (score 0):

I take flat file from Azure blob storage and converted into nested array in Azure data factory.

Flat file:

[image]

I created pipeline and implemented dataflow in pipeline.
Dataflow:

[image]

Source of dataflow:

[image]

I have taken derived column and created products column with two sub columns name and price with below expression

```
@(name=Pname,       price=price)
```

[image]

Sub column name:

[image]

Sub column name:

[image]

I implemented Aggregate activity and applied group by on employeeNumber,employeeName,id,Cname columns.
Image for reference

[image]

I applied aggregate on products column applied collect operation to convert products to array with below expression:

```
collect(products)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Data preview of Aggregate:

[image]

I implemented derived column on the aggregate and created customers column with sub columns id, name, products with below expression:

```
@(id=id,        name=Cname,     products=products)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Sub column Id:

[image]

Sub column name:

[image]

Sub column products:

[image]

I applied select function on derive d column to retrieve employeeNumber, employeeName, customers column
Image for reference:

[image]

Data preview of select:

[image]

I applied aggregate on customers column applied collect operation to convert products to array with below expression:

```
collect(customers)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Data preview of Aggregate:

[image]

[image]

I connected it to sink to store the nested array Json file in blob storage.

Sink:

[image]

I run the pipeline It run successfully.

Image for reference:

[image]

The output file stored in my blob container

Output:

```
{"employeeNumber":"00001",
 "employeeName":"John Doe",
 "customers":[
 {     "id":"1111",
       "name":"John Smith",
       "products":[
          { "name":"RVS",
            "price":"2.0"
          }, 
          {"name":"GHI",
           "price":"3.0"
          },
          {"name":"QRS",
           "price":"4.0"
          }
        ]
  },
  {     "id":"99999",
        "name":"Jane Doe",
        "products":  [
           {"name":"XYZ",
            "price":"2.0"
           },
           {"name":"ABC",
            "price":"3.0"
           }
         ]
  }]
}
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much!!!.  I had the right idea but was starting at the top of the hierarchy with the struct and aggregates.  Need to work for the bottom up.